# nftablesによるNATが機能せず困っています

Tags: network, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi 4Bの内蔵無線LANと内蔵有線LANでNATを設定しようとしています。

無線、有線二つのNICを使ってネットワークを分離し、有線側に数台のデバイスが繋がった小さなネットワーク、無線側にはPCが繋がっています。
無線側ネットワークにあるPCから、ラズパイを経由して有線側のネットワークのデバイスと通信したいです。

いろいろなサイトを参考にしながらnftablesを設定してみたのですが、上記の通信ができません。

何か解決の糸口をご教授ください。

net.ipv4.ip_forwardは1になっています。
nft list ruleset の結果は以下の通りです。

```
table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        }
}
table ip nat {
        chain prerouting {
                type nat hook prerouting priority filter; policy accept;
                iif "wlan0" tcp dport 683 dnat to 192.168.1.100:683
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nft の設定は問題ないと思います。

戻りパケットのルーティング (有線側サーバーから PC)  はどうなっていますか？
有線側サーバーから PC へ戻りパケットが Raspberry Pi を経由しないとダメです。
DNAT したものを元に戻せないので。

Comment: ありがとうございます。戻りパケットということですが、そのポート番号は予想できませんよね？どういったっていにしたらいいのでしょうか・・？

Comment: kernel が DNAT した情報を保持しているので、Raspberry Pi が戻りパケットについてポート番号を気にする必要はありません。

Comment: nftablesの設定ではなく、有線側サーバでの設定ということでしょうか？
組み込み系のデバイスで、細かな設定変更が出来ないのです。デフォルトゲートウェイはラズパイの有線側アドレスを設定してあります。

Comment: > デフォルトゲートウェイはラズパイの有線側アドレスを設定してあります。

であれば大丈夫なはずです。
Raspberry Pi で 2つのシェルを用意して、それぞれで "tcpdump -nn -i wlan0 port 683", "tcpdump -nn -i eth0 port 683" (eth0 は有線側インターフェース名) でパケットキャプチャしてどこまで届いているのか確認するといいと思います。
また、nft の他に iptables や、iptables ベースのファイアーウォールなどが有効になっていないでしょうか？

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございます。
原因はデフォルトゲートウェイの設定ミスでした。

教えていただいたtcpdumpを見ると無線、有線どちらもきちんと転送されているのを確認できたので、サーバ側設定を再確認したところデフォルトゲートウェイが間違えていました。

とても勉強になりました！ありがとうございました！